# Blender Flame Smoke animation rendering

Tags: rendering, animation

I am playing around with my first fire animation attempt.  Settings are done but I have the following 2 difficulties,

1. I would like the flame animation to be a constant one.  As it is it starts from nothing at frame 0, develops into a flame at frame 66 and stays constant till frame 100.
   I would like it as in the part from frame 66 to 100.  I tried starting the animation at frame 66 but it did not work.
   [image]
2. The flame is not rendering, only the smoke is.  I tried to enable the volumetrics as in the tutorial I saw but there is not enabling button.

[image]

Here I uploaded the file I am working on.

[image]

Thanks for any help given.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To display the flame, connect the *Volume Info/ Flame* socket to the *Blackbody intensity* socket of your *Principled Volume* shader

[image]

As regards having a sustained flame, without the moment when it "ramps up", I believe the easiest way is to just bake your simulation cache for many frames, then remove the first 66 frames from the animation (*Render > Start > 67*). It's impossible to skip the baking of the phase where the flames develop, because you can't easily create an already-burning starting condition.

You could in principle move the smoke cache 66 frames forward, but it's hacky (requires moving several files manually) and I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If I understood I would bake the simulation normally from frame one to hundred.  Then after removing frame 1 to 66.  Still my first noobish try.

Comment: If you want a 100 frame long animation, bake from 1 to 167. Then only render your animation frames 67 to 167!

Comment: I just tried to add the volume info as you said but when I drop down the input menu  Volume info is not present.  Am I in a different setting then yours?   Photo added in main post.